# Smart Client : List Grid?

Tags: smartclient

While setting data into List grid. Some extra space is coming after last record.

```
isc.CustomListGrid.create({ 
        dataSource: "DeviceDiscoveryDataSource",
        ID:"deviceDiscoveryListGrid",
        autoDraw: false,
        //showAllRecords: true,
        paddingAsLayoutMargin:false,
        autoFitMaxRecords:2000,
        showFilterEditor:true,
        filterOnKeypress:true,
        filterLocalData: true,
        alternateRecordStyles:true,
        autoFetchData:true,
        showRecordComponents: true,
        showRecordComponentsByCell: true,
        cellHeight:35,
        emptyCellValue:"-",
        canSort:false,
        canGroupBy:false,
        canPickFields:true,
        bodyProperties: { canSelectText:true },
        fields: [{
            name: "deviceName",
            type: "text",
            title: "Device Name",
             align: "center",
            width:200        
    }]
});
```

Where I am wrong I am not getting. Please Help me.

Comment: Hi, Can you create a static example that behaves the same? I can't see immediately what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set virtualScrolling property to false in the ListGrid. When rendering components in each row, SmartClient does not exactly know how much space it will need, hence the blank space after the last record.

More about this: http://www.smartclient.com/docs/10.0/a/b/c/go.html#attr..ListGrid.virtualScrolling